# How to calculate the mean of a new group?

Tags: r

How to calculate the mean `age` of the group,aftering regroup the data?
For example:

Data:

```
age gender
20    0
27    0
23    1
...   ...
```

Code:

```
library(plyr)
gender <- revalue(as.factor(gender), c("0"="F", "1"="M"))
table(gender )
```

And get:

```
gender
F    M 
30   41
```

How can I calculate the mean `age` of the gender group of each `F` and `M`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a `tidyverse` approach with the package `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df <-
  data.frame(
    age = c(20,27,23),
    gender = c(0,0,1)
  )

df %>% 
  mutate(gender = if_else(gender == 0, "F","M")) %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>% 
  summarise(mean_age = mean(age))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  gender mean_age
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 F          23.5
2 M          23
```